# Watching './**/*.js' causes excessive CPU usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I need to watch all folders including the current one for changes. Therefore I used

```
gulp.task('start', () => {
    if (node) node.kill()
    node = spawn('node', ['server.js'], {
        stdio: 'inherit'
    })
    node.on('close', function(code) {
        if (code === 8) {
            gulp.log('Error detected, waiting for changes...');
        }
    });
});

gulp.watch(['./**/*.js'], ['start']);

gulp.task('default', ['start', 'watch']);

process.on('exit', function() {
    if (node) node.kill()
});
```

but it causes 100% CPU usage. If I use it only on a single folder (which contains 99% of all files which need to be watched) like 'api/**/*.js` there's hardly any CPU usage.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Clarifying the obvious: are you sure that that's the only change (`.` -> `api`) between high and low CPU use, or could something else have changed between tests?

Comment: The watch task itself is not responsible for the CPU usage. Please show us your `start` task and what it is doing.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I double-checked it again. What I described in the post is still the case.
I also added the `start` code to the question.

Comment: The other folders don't conain some kind of build files, do they? Like results from the 'watch' task? I've sometimes accidentally hit infinite loop when the buld results were not excluded from the watch glob.

Comment: @Hedge Are you watching `node_modules` by any chance?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are watching all `.js` files in all directories and subdirectories of your project. Which includes `node_modules`. Depending on how many dependencies you have in your project and how many dependencies those dependencies have etc. you might be watching thousands of `.js` files.

You should limit your watch glob to only those directories where source files are located:

```
gulp.watch(['api/**/*.js', 'app/**/*.js', ...], ['start']);
```

Alternatively you can try to exclude your `node_modules` folder and any other folders that don't contain source files (like your build destination folder):

```
gulp.watch(['api/**/*.js', '!node_modules/**/*.js', ...], ['start']);
```

Comment: oh how could I miss that. Of course it was because of `node_modules`

Answer (score 19):

gulp v3's `watch` had [known CPU usage issues](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/651) for almost 5 years.  This is because gulp uses polling (`fs.watchFile`) to detect changes.

- This has allegedly been fixed in gulp 4.0 (released Dec 2018), but there are [reports](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2245) of similar issues.
- For versions < 4, the workaround recommendation is to increase the polling interval.

  ```
  gulp.watch('**/*.js', { interval: 2000 }, ...)
  ```

  (the default is 100)
- [@Sven's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36846235/201952) is also very sound -- there's likely no reason to watch your node_modules or build folders.

Comment: I've been having this problem even after upgrading to 4.0 - at first CPU usage is nearly 0% with gulp watch, but after some time (a couple of hours) it goes to 100% for some reason (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2245). AFAIK the `interval` option has been removed...